# - In plugin 'org.asciidoctor.convert' type 'org.asciidoctor.gradle.AsciidoctorTask' property 'logDocuments' is annotated with @Optional

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, asciidoctor

I am using Gradle 9.0. what is the ascii version that is compatible to run and facing below error

- In plugin 'org.asciidoctor.convert' type 'org.asciidoctor.gradle.AsciidoctorTask' property 'logDocuments' is annotated with @Optional but that is not allowed for 'Console' properties.